# Docker cp into a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hello I need to make a copy of a conf file that is located in my docker. I want to use it as a VOLUME, i don`t care if is in a Dockerfile or docker-compose... I need it to work to edit my confs. Thanks!

Comment: I want one file from Docker, like something.cfg that is make on my docker machine, but I need it on my host to edit and make it works on Docker.

Comment: In gist VOLUMES allow you to map host folder to a container folder. So what you are asking for is already available in your question? what exactly do u need help with?

Comment: I suspect that it's a language barrier issue? Why do you need to create the file within Docker and then edit it outside? Would the other way around be easier?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then maybe try something like this:

First create a "dummy" config file in a directory that you will map as a volume

```
mkdir mapdir
touch mapdir/myconfig.cfg
```

In your `Dockerfile` you'll do what you need to do with that config file. Maybe as part of a `CMD` clause

```
FROM ...
RUN ...
CMD ["sed", "<editstuff>, "mapdir/myconfig.cfg" ]
```

Then build and run your container

```
docker build .
docker run --name mycontainer -v mapdir:mapdir ...
```

It's still a strange approach, but if you absolute can only change the config file from *within* your container, give this a go.